# Use of sound in iPhone app - adding an action and grouping buttons

Tags: iphone, class, file, audio

I have been checking video tutuorials on playing the use of a sound in an iPhone app. As I am building one and found a few tips, I am stuck with two questions regarding the Interface builder:

1. After bringing a new button in the View, I am looking at the button's View Identity, but there is no Class Actions item under the Class Identity (in the video tutorials there is). Is there something I needed to add or is just the newer version? Mine only has the Class Identity and Interface Builder Identity. How do I add an action in View Identity? In the videos there are + buttons that generate Class actions.
2. If i have a menu with 250 buttons (let's say a tips list menu) and I want the same sound generated every time the user touches any of the buttons, should I connect the sound file manually to each of the 250 buttons or is there a way of gathering all 250 in one place and connected only once? How do i gather them all together for that?

I really appreciate the answers. Thank you!
Sorin

Comment: As for your first question, UIView cannot fire any action methods. You need to change it to UIControl, which is, a subclass of UIView. UIControl can fire actions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first question is that - due to the newer changes - the Action class could be found under "Classes" tab in the library panel (select the object from the top half you wish to inspect and the lower half of the screen has tabs for Lineage, Definitions, Outlets and Actions.)